# How to Slide the Activity like new facebook app using Right button with rightmenu and also left button with left menu

Tags: android

Please any one tell me how to do that. i try lot of but i get only from left to right sliding.i use the sideMenu libray also but i cant perform the sliding from left menu to left button and Right menu to right button.

Please give me the solution.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/

It works for me, but don't forget to use

```
getSlidingMenu().setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT_RIGHT);
```

for being able to use menu on both sides.